# Running AWS Log Agent from inside a Fargate container

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Trying to run the AWS Logs Agent inside a docker container running on AWS ECS Fargate.

This has been working fine under EC2 for several years. Under Fargate context, it does not seem to be able to resolve the task role being passed to it.

Permissions on the Task Role should be good... I've even tried giving it full CloudWatch permissions to eliminate that as a reason.

I've managed to hack the python based launcher script to add a `--debug` flag which gave me this in the log:

```
Caught retryable HTTP exception while making metadata service request to
 http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials
```

It does not appear to be properly resolving the credentials that are passed into the task as the 'Task Role'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a hack workaround, that may illustrate what I believe to be a bug or inadequacy in the agent. I had to hack the launcher script using sed as follows:

```
sed -i "s|HTTPS_PROXY|AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI=$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI HTTPS_PROXY|" 
/var/awslogs/bin/awslogs-agent-launcher.sh
```

This essentially de-references the ENV variable holding the URI for retrieving the task role and passes it to the agent's launcher.

It results in something like this:

```
/usr/bin/env -i AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI=/v2/credentials/f4ca7e30-b73f-4919-ae14-567b1262b27b (etc...)
```

With this in place, I restart the log agent and it works as expected.

Note that you can do something like this to add `--debug` flag to the launcher also which was very helpful in trying to figure out where it went astray.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can use the new 'Unified AWS Logs Agent', that would be preferred. I assume it won't have a problem under Fargate, but my linux version was not compatible with it because of a custom init system that comes from dockerimage_base (my_init).

Answer (score 0):

When you execute ECS container with FARGATE configuration, it looks for the credentials stored inside container. But in case of AWS ECS FARGATE or AWS EKS it fetches the credentials from an environment variable "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" which basically is HTTP endpoint.

Please refer below AWS DOC
[Container Credential Provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-container-credentials.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).